# Difference between deferred execution and Lazy evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-nhibernate

Could you please let me know what is the exact deference between deferred execution  and Lazy evaluation in C#?These two are used synonymously.Could some one please explain the difference with an example??

Comment: Check out Jon Skeets blog post on the subject: [http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx)

Comment: Alright, you win. Slow/lazy me :)

Comment: Duplicate, by an user named with the same name of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515796/2515920

Comment: deferred and Lazy are same.

Comment: Updated link to Jon Skeet's blog post: [Just how lazy are you?](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you/)

Answer (score 32):

In practice, they mean essentially the same thing.  However, it's preferable to use the term *deferred*.

- **Lazy** means *"don't do the work until you absolutely have to."*
- **Deferred** means *"don't compute the result until the caller actually uses it."*

In practice, when the caller decides to use the result of an evaluation (i.e. start iterating through an `IEnumerable<T>`), that is precisely the point at which the "work" needs to be done (such as issuing a query to the database).

The term **deferred** is more specific/descriptive as to what's actually going on.  When I say that I am *lazy*, it means that I *avoid doing unnecessary work*; it's ambiguous as to what that *really* implies.  However, when I say that execution/evaluation is *deferred*, it essentially means that I am not giving you the real result at all, but rather a *ticket you can use to claim the result*.  I *defer* actually going out and *getting* that result until you *claim* it.

Please use the term *deferred* when discussing the subject as it pertains to C#.  *Lazy* is a vaguer version.

**Note:** Lazy *execution/evaluation* is different from lazy *loading* or *fetching* in the context of a *sequence*.  **Lazy loading** and **eager loading** are terms used to describe how elements of a sequence are loaded.  When a sequence is loaded *lazily*, it means that whatever is generating the sequence does just enough work to load *one element at a time*.  When a sequence is *eagerly* loaded, the *entire* sequence is loaded all at once and stored in a local buffer.  Different usage requirements call for different loading patterns.

Comment: If someone needs a code to see how those two are working, i prepare Console App that shows difference between them: https://github.com/jakubmaguza/Lazy-vs-Deferred-vs-Normal/blob/master/src/Main.cs

Answer (score 4):

In process Deferred/lazy evaluation are same.

LINQ queries use lazy (or deferred) evaluation, not actually fetching any data until the result is used.

In c# Deferred/lazy evaluation does the same process, a query is not executed, until it is requested.

Ex:

> ```
> DataContext context = new DataContext(); 
>  var query = from customer in context.Customers   
>             where customer.City == "Delhi"  
>             select customer; // Query does not execute here, it wont fetch                           
>                               to database to retrieve data   
>
> foreach (var Customer in query) // Query executes here  
> {  
>    Console.WriteLine(Customer.Name);  
> }
> ```

It executes only if immediate executions is used like projection/aggregate functions.etc.
Ex:

> ```
>  DataContext context = new DataContext(); 
>         var query = (from customer in context.Customers 
>          where customer.City == "Delhi" 
>         select  customer).Count(); // Query execute here
> ```

.Count() which triggers and executes the query immediately.