# How to Order/Sort List<T> using Lambda expression in C#5?

Tags: list, sorting, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I'm converting my application from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5 Framework and there is a change in the `List<>` definition.
My old code looked like this (.Net 4.0):

```
List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
list.Add(new Customer("Smith", "John", "Sydney", 45));    
list.Add(new Customer("Mitchell", "Brad", "New York", 52));
list.Add(new Customer("Baker", "William", "Cape Town", 21)); 
list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Using .Net 4.5 (C#5) the `List<T>.OrderBy()` method is gone and only [`List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/3da4abas.aspx) is available, but it looks like there is no possibility to use a Lambda expression with this method.

Is there any option other than defining a `IComparer` for every `<T>`?
If there is really no option for a Lambda expression, I could life with a generic `IComparer`, but how to choose the property to be compared?

Solved/Edit:

```
using Linq;
[...]
List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
list.Add(new Customer("Smith", "John", "Sydney", 45));    
list.Add(new Customer("Mitchell", "Brad", "New York", 52));
list.Add(new Customer("Baker", "William", "Cape Town", 21)); 
list.OrderBy(x => x.Name); //list stays unordered
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();  // list content is now ordered
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List<T>.OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb534966) is not gone, it's still an extension method

You have to use

```
using System.Linq;
```

to make it work

In your code, you should use "list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);"

Comment: Thanks, but why is it an extension and not part of List? How should I know if there is somewhere an extension I could need? Maybe my "mistake" was to clean the using before converting :(

Comment: OrderBy is an extension method of IEnumerable<T> and List<T> inherit of IEnumerable<T> so you can use it in List<T>. The intellisence doesn't tell you much if there is an extension method that you could use, so I guess the only way would be to look at the msdn documentation

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to search, when you don't know what you are looking for. Also there seems to be a change in handling the OrderBy, as you can see in my edit above.

Comment: I guess they made OrderBy lazy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530755/difference-between-deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-c-sharp