# IQueryable vs ICollection (List)

Tags: c#, linq, icollection

I have such a case study:

**`ToList()` case:**

```
    List<CategoryType> categories = (from c in categoryTypes where c.IsSysParam == isSysParamCategory select new CategoryType { Code = c.Code, CreateDate = c.CreateDate, EditDate = c.EditDate, IsProductCategory = c.IsProductCategory, IsSysParam = c.IsSysParam, Name = c.Name, TypeId = c.TypeId, ValueTypes = new List<ValueType>() }).ToList();

    List<ValueType> valueTypeList = new List<ValueType>();
    foreach (var c in categories.ToList())
    {
        valueTypeList = categoryTypes.Where(x => x.TypeId == c.TypeId).SelectMany(v => v.ValueTypes).Where(v => v.ParentValueId == null).ToList();
        c.ValueTypes = valueTypeList;
    }
```

[image]

**`IQueryable` case:**

When I change in first query - `List<CategoryType>` to `IQueryable<CategoryType>` and remove `ToList()` from the end of query then I dont have any result:

[image]

**Question:**

*I am asking for an explanation, I do not understand why this is happening.* I know that the `IQueryable` makes some part of the work on the database side.

**Edit:**
The code is working, pictures shows the final effect.

I have:

```
  public IQueryable<CategoryType> CategoryTypePagination { get; set; }
```

and in the end of `ToList()` case:

```
this.CategoryTypePagination = categories.AsQueryable();
```

in `IQueryable` case just removed `.AsQueryable()`

Comment: Post the *actual* code, not screenshots and descriptions.  The code and screenshots don't match. The object definitions are missing. You claim you were able to assign an IQueryable to a *List<T>* variable without compilation errors?

Comment: I think [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/) is much more helpfull than my explanation attempts

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - I edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at ["Deferred Query Execution" and "Immediate Query Execution"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)

Comment: The code sets the `ValueTypes` property directly - even though in the second "snippets" the value is supposed to be an IQueyrable that just can't be assigned to a List<T>

Answer (score 0):

Accrodingly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947923/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable-in-the-repository-pattern-lazy-loading), `IQueryable` uses something called [lazy loading](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading).

So the results of `IQueryable` aren't loaded until they are first used, for example in `Sum`, `ToList` or `ToArray` methods, while `ToList` requieres data to be loaded. Thus you see the difference after initailizing both objects.

Comment: It's more likely that the code doesn't even run. It's trying to assign an IQueryable to a List<T> variable. This should throw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, OP stated that he changed the type to `IQueryable` and removed `ToList()` method. As can be also seen in [pictures, code runs well.

Comment: The screenshots don't match the code. They are from a *different* snippet entirely. The OP doesn't explain what changes were made - IQueryable doesn't have a `.Count` property. If `ValueTypes` is still a list, how was an *IQueryable* assigned to it? And since `ValueTypes` contains the query's *root* results its count wouldn't be affected by lazy loading