# How to find the max id of any table.

Tags: c#, linq

I would like something like this:

```
    public int NumberStudent()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (db.Tbl_Student.ToList().Count() > 0)
            i = db. Tbl_Student.Max(d => d.id);
        return i;
     }
```

However, I would like to use it on any table:

```
   public int FindMaxId(string TableName)
     {
       int i =0;
        if ('db.'+TableName+'.ToList().Count() > 0' )
           i = db. TableName.Max(d => d.id);
        return i ;
     }
```

I know it is wrong, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: `.ToList().Count() > 0` could very likely be replaced with `.Any()` it will improve your performance too because it does not need to enumerate the table twice.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable` extension method [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) for this.

```
var maxId = db.Tbl_Student.Select(x => x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

In general, if you do `Q.DefaultIfEmpty(D)`, it means:

> If `Q` isn't empty, give me `Q`; otherwise, give me `[ D ]`.

Comment: Ah, my bad.. I see now that this will actually work for any table, my bad. +1

Comment: `var maxId = db.Tbl_Student.Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0`

Answer (score 4):

Below I have written a simple wrapper around the existing `Max` extension method that allows you provide an empty source (the table you were talking about).

Instead of throwing an exception, it will just return the default value of zero.

**Original**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int MaxId<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        if (source.Any())
        {
            return source.Max(selector);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This was my attempt, which as noted by Timothy is actually quite inferior. This is because the sequence will be enumerated twice. Once when calling `Any` to check if the source sequence has any elements, and again when calling `Max`.

**Improved**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int MaxId<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
    }
}
```

This implementation uses Timothy's approach. By calling `DefaultIfEmpty`, we are making use of [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515796/deferred-execution-and-eager-evaluation) and the sequence will only be enumerated when calling `Max`. In addition we are now using `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable` which means we don't have to enumerate the source before calling this method. As Scott said, should you need it you can create an overload that uses `IEnumerable` too.

In order to use the extension method, you just need to provide a delegate that returns the id of the source type, exactly the same way you would for `Max`.

```
public class Program
{
    YourContext context = new YourContext();

    public int MaxStudentId()
    {
        return context.Student.MaxId(s => s.Id);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Max student id: {0}", MaxStudentId());
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static int MaxId<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer. There's a lesser-known LINQ method for this that already exists.

Comment: Another good approach, definitely. This cat can be skinned in many ways! Upvoted :)

Comment: The point was that the body of your `MaxId` helper method could simply be replaced with `return source.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();`. Favor composing existing operations over making new ones from scratch. Your `MaxId` method would actually enumerate `source` twice.

Comment: That is quite true and thanks for the tip. I will update the snippet using your approach, if that's okay?

Comment: Perfectly fine with me. Maybe even make note of the first implementation you had and then why it's better to switch it over (enumerate source only once instead of twice). Also, you could make it an `IQueryable` extension method instead so that it can be done database-side rather than client-side.

Comment: The one last thing I would change is make two overloads One that takes in `IEnumerable<TSource>` and one that takes in `IQueryable<TSource>` as the IQueryable provider may result in a smaller query to the DB if it can get away with it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Hopefully someone will find this useful.

Comment: thanks Zac Blazic .but how can i use your class Extensions .can you make an example with one table.

Comment: I have updated the example to more closely resemble what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`db.Tbl_Student.Aggregate(0, (maxId, s) => Math.Max(maxId, s.Id))`
or
`db.Tbl_Student.Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0`

Comment: thanks. but i wanna use this for any table. i wanna pass name of table   and it returns maxid.