# Regex fast iteration MatchCollection indices

Tags: c#, regex, linq

How can I iterate a MatchCollection Index property of each `Match` most efficiently? I have many `Regex` objects in my code and I need to iterate through all `Match` indices but in the VS profiler I see that a simple Linq query

```
regex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Index)
```

and the inside function:

```
IEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

takes almost half of the execution time. Is there some way to hardcode this? Maybe pointer jumps through internal structures or some other methods to avoid `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the part that takes the most time is actually: `regex.Matches(text)` (the regex match itself)

Comment: but profiler say's MoveNext is most consuming function...

Comment: @eocron Because of *deferred execution*, your regex doesn't run until you start the enumeration. But the real problem isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted by @L.B your Linq expression is subject to [*deferred execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515796/deferred-execution-and-eager-evaluation). That is, if you iterate through your MatchCollection at each step your `Regex` will be executed to provide the next `Match` and that's most likely the performance hit you observe.

As a matter of fact, `Regex` are pretty heavy. But there are some tweaks you can make to improve the performance (see[`Regex`best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx)).

What you might want to try is to apply a compiled `Regex`:

```
Regex comp10 = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: thx, i forgot about deferred execution :) i added compiled option a long before uestion, and i think thats a bottleneck ...if only i had regexlike fast enough automaton indexe:(